# maximizing frequency

Tags: r

I am trying to find the area with thickest density.  I have newborn numbers by day for which I am trying to find the series of 7 consecutive days that would produce the highest frequency. So the start and end dates are not tied to any particular day of the week the period can start on any day but would end in 7 days from the start.  I know I can iterate through the various starts but is there a more efficient mathematical solution?

Comment: Can you say more about your situation & your data? You want the highest density of what? Are you in a neonatal unit? Do you just want to know what day most babies are born?

Comment: @gung it looks like trying to find which week had the most babies born, from daily data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving average filter with 7 day long window will do this, then simply pick the max value.